# Skew-symmetric matrix absolute value and row/column sums

Tags: linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

I'm looking at an algorithm that takes a square matrix $M$ containing real numbers and calculates the skew-symmetric part like so:

$ S = (M - M^t)/2 $

It then calculates the absolute value of $S$:

$ S_{abs} = |S| $

*Edit: The absolute values of the individual elements*

Finally, it calculates the row sums and column sums of $S_{abs}$ and compares them.

My understanding is that $S_{abs}$ should be a symmetric matrix, and as such, the row sums and column sums of $S_{abs}$ should be identical. Am I missing something where they could be different?

Comment: You are right, it will be symmetric and thus $r_i = c_i^T$ (rows, and columns)

Comment: $S$ doesn't even need to be skew-symmetric. Its [absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829437) $|S|=\sqrt{S^tS}$ is symmetric (and positive) by definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval I actually didn't realize there was a special definition for the absolute value of a matrix. In the case of this algorithm, it's calculating the absolute values of the individual elements

Comment: Then you should edit your post to clarify this. Anyway, why ask? Wasn't the answer obvious? Where was your doubt? Were you doubting that the "absolute value" (in your sense) of a skew-symmetric matrix is symmetric?? Or that the rows and columns of a symmetric matrix are identical???

Comment: @AnneBauval I was asking because it means there is code in a several-year-old widely used algorithm I'm reading through that does literally nothing, and I'm trying to figure out why it might have been included. Given the confirmation here, it seems the author missed this property. Skew-symmetric matrices are new to me and I wanted to be 100% sure there isn't some non-obvious corner case that will come back to bite me in the future after I remove the unnecessary code.